# ChartJs - Disable Animations

Tags: angular, chartjs-2.6.0

I am using ChartJS inside of an angular 7 application. I want to disable the animations on my line series because the series is constantly being updated. I have tried setting

```
options: {
    animations: false 
}
```

as well as

```
options: {
    animation: {
        duration: 0
    }
}
```

Neither of these worked.

Are there any other options/functions I need to add to the Chart configuration to disable animations?

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html: the name of the property is `duration`, not `durations`.

Comment: Thanks! That was just a typo in the OP. I found the answer shortly after posting the question.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer referenced [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html) in the documentation. I just needed to pass a '0' in the update function like so:

```
this.chart.update(0);
```

Comment: chart.js 4 now uses this.chart.update('none') instead.